# Unable to execute dex because of java heap space in eclipse with a tiny android application

Tags: android, eclipse, heap-memory, dex

I have an android application that only has one jar import which is 4 mb in size (Symja https://code.google.com/p/symja/)  Literally the only code in the project is creating a new textview and setting it as the content view.  But I am getting the error(s):

```
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Java heap space
Unable to execute dex: Java heap space
```

I have another android project which is alot bigger, almost 20,000 lines of code and it runs in seconds.  My eclipse.ini has the following settings:

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

I do not know why I cannot run this project.  So any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read, that symja library needs **Java version 1.6**. But your Eclipse uses Java 1.5. Maybe, it's a problem.

Answer (score 14):

Try the following:

```
Right click your project. Go to Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export.
Uncheck the check box against your included library. Press OK and run the project.
```

On doing this Eclipse will take only the classes which are needed in the code, from the jar instead of storing all the classes from the jar.

Comment: Yes thats right, I am getting the Java Heap Error, when I Unchecked all the library, it executes but application is crashing on the device, please help me..

Answer (score 2):

Modify the -XmsAm and -XmxBm paremeters in eclipse.ini so that they are large enough. The default is -Xms40m -Xmx384m. Try changing them both to -Xms512m -Xmx512m and restart eclipse to see if that helps. If not, continue to increase the values and restart eclipse until either one of two things happens:

Your build completes.
Eclipse won't restart because you don't have enough memory.
eclipse.ini is located at /etc/eclipse.ini in Ubuntu (assuming you installed Eclipse from the Ubuntu repositories).