# Can not run project after adding google play services to project

Tags: android

I am making a android application with needs google map.

I created a new project in eclipse and compiled it on an android phone, it worked, but when I import the google-play-services_lib to my workspace and added a reference to it in my project, it doesn't compile, hangs up for a while with the status bar showing (launching project 100%) and displays an error "Unable to execute dex: Java heap space"

Update:
I also tried changing the eclipse.ini file to increase memory limit to 512 and 1024, but no use

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

PS: searched alot before posting a question

Comment: this has nothing to do with the library project. Try increasing the space. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412302/unable-to-execute-dex-because-of-java-heap-space-in-eclipse-with-a-tiny-android and this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379037/unable-to-execute-dex-java-heap-space-java-heap-space

Comment: delete bin folder and R file from project restart eclipse i hope it helps you

Comment: check updated question, i tried that @Raghunandan

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Java heap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943712/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-unable-to-execute-dex-java-heap-space)

The gist is: Keep increasing the Xms and Xmx values until it either works or you run out of physical memory.

in eclipse.ini

E.g.:
`-XX:MaxPermSize=1536m
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx1536m`

Comment: just updated my question, what should I increase more

Comment: thanks mate, i increased it to -Xms2028m -Xmx4072m and it finally did work

Comment: @Richard it is memory limit so Xmx is max usage memory by eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and since my pc has 2 GB memory I had to find another solution. I compiled the project from command line - so without Eclipse using [gradle](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html).