# Refrencing to Google Play Services causes Java heap space error

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

Adding Google Play Services refrence to my project (in Eclipse) causes Java heap space error.

It seems like it takes about 130K of memory when i examine task manager.

What can i do about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can not run project after adding google play services to project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919229/can-not-run-project-after-adding-google-play-services-to-project)