# Java heap error after adding google play library

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

My app was working fine but then I decided to add google play ads into my project so I added their library to my project but after I added them, I can't run my project and eclipse shows 
"Unable to execute dex: Java heap space
Java heap space"

I browsed all the questions and tried to resolve and not a single thing helped. Plz help me with this issue.

PS: when I remove the google play services library my app works without any problem

Comment: Please explain, completely and precisely, how you "tried to resolve". For example, did you increase the maximum heap size of Eclipse?

Comment: yea I tried increasing heap size till 4800M but it doesnt work. I tried other solutions like deleting bin folders..etc.

Comment: i also had the same problem , did you find solution to this ?

Comment: i also have the same problem, let me know if any solution is  available.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

Keep increasing the Xms and Xmx values in eclipse.ini file.

reference link:

[Can not run project after adding google play services to project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919229/can-not-run-project-after-adding-google-play-services-to-project)