# Google play services lib Java heap space error

Tags: java, android, memory, heap-memory, heap-size

I read a tutorial from Google site there is written that the old way of using stand alone admob SDK is now deprecated, and we have to use the new way by using Google Play Services lib.  I import into Eclipse and then add Google Play Services lib into my app "hello world" as a sample, but when I run the project it loads for 1 minute and then it doesn't run and it shows an error:

> Unable to execute Java heap space error

Can any one tell me that how to put an ads into an app?

Comment: If all you have thus far is a small "hello world" app, you should be able to paste your full code here, and someone may be better able to help you. Your app works without the Google Play Services library imported?

Comment: My apps works without the Google Play Services library but when i add a google play services lib into any app it doesnot run it loads till 1 or 2 minutes and then it shows an error Unable to execute Delvik format Java heap space error so how can i run the project

Comment: I had exact the same error. Here the answer

[click here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919229/can-not-run-project-after-adding-google-play-services-to-project