# Android - Google Play Services - Lib Dependencies

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, android-library

I have gone through all the solutions mentioned in stackoverflow.

Android ADT & SDK-Tools Version : 23.0.4 
Google Play Services : version 20

1. 'Google-play-services-lib' library project is imported into the workspace and add the library     project to main project.

[image]

2. In 'Google-play-services-lib' library project, google-play-services.jars is in

   ***'libs' folder and it is reflecting in Android-private dependencies.***

[image]

3. In Main project, 'Google-play-services-lib' libraray project is added as library project from

   ***right Click Properties --> Click Android --> add --> added the library project.***

[image]

Note: All Clean and restart of eclipse is tried out.

Anyone have what's wrong with the dependencies. The google drive classes are not found and getting the following errors.

```
10-11 02:51:14.640: W/dalvikvm(22107): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 6146: Lcom/google/android/gms/drive/DriveFolder;.getDriveId ()Lcom/google/android/gms/drive/DriveId;
10-11 02:51:14.640: D/dalvikvm(22107): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x000f
10-11 02:51:14.645: D/AndroidRuntime(22107): Shutting down VM
10-11 02:51:14.645: W/dalvikvm(22107): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415262a0)

10-11 02:51:14.650: E/AndroidRuntime(22107): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    10-11 02:51:14.650: E/AndroidRuntime(22107): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil
    10-11 02:51:14.650: E/AndroidRuntime(22107):    at com.ss.watsappcomedypic.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
```

Console Error:

```
Dx bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0033.0000) ...while parsing com/google/android/gms/common/internal/safeparcel/a.class ...while processing com/google/android/gms/common/internal/safeparcel/a.class
```

Comment: I'm curious. Is this a new project? Why are you still using Eclipse?

Comment: add `<meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />` to the application in the manifest. You will come to know if the library has been imported properly.

Comment: I have already added that meta-data in android manifest file.

Comment: i m getting tis error in console  ...                                   Dx bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0033.0000)
...while parsing com/google/android/gms/common/internal/safeparcel/a.class
...while processing com/google/android/gms/common/internal/safeparcel/a.class

Comment: where are you testing this, make sure your testing device has the latest gms update.

Comment: i ma facing the same issue. Is there some problem with google play services rev 20? I tried my same code on another PC having google play services rev 19. It is running fine there. can someone help us please?

Answer (score 1):

Google Play services version 20 needs JDK1.7 or later.

```
 Eclipse - Preferences - java - compiler - Compiler Compliance level - change from 1.6 to 1.7
```

Comment: +1. However, after compiling google-play-services with 1.7 I can't build my project(that uses play services) anymore due to `GC overhead memory limit exceeded` error. Do you have any experience with that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919229/can-not-run-project-after-adding-google-play-services-to-project

Comment: tried that of course. Didn't work for me. Did you have the same problem after switching to java 1.7 ?

Comment: i didn't face such issue after switching.