# can't run app on eclipse using google play service

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, google-play-services, eclipse-adt

Hi I'm trying to make a very simle and basic application for android that will use google maps (v2). As for know the only thing I do is that I want to display a map so I've done everything like in documentation:

I have my API key set in manifest

I've added permissions

I have v4 support

I've downloaded google play service, imported it to SDK and added as reference

My problem is when I add the reference eclipse is going crazy while starting app and it going to memory limit. WHen I increse the memory limit in eclipse.ini after 5 minutes I get infor that apk can't be installed. There is no problem with running the app when I  have no reference to google play service.

Seriously I need a tip where to find the problem. I'm after 10 hours of searching and I can't run the basic map :/

Comment: what did you change in the .ini file?

Comment: are you using old computer? how much ram do you have?

Comment: @Fahim accourding to few topics from SO I've changed memory limits from standard to 2GB

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira I have 6GB ram. Computer has 2 or 3 years so it is not so old. I never had this kind of problems and I've worked with more massive applications that 1 class + 4mb library

Comment: how about restart your eclipse?

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira done it about 50 times over last 10 hours. I need to do it every time after this crash. I've also restarted my phone, any my computer

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I found the solution. It is in some case realted with [Can not run project after adding google play services to project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919229/can-not-run-project-after-adding-google-play-services-to-project)

But the key is not to extend it up as much as you can (trust me, I've done this) - I think it is all about setting proper memory settings (in relation one to another)

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1536m
```

This setting helped me. For example when I had `-Xms2048m` and `-Xmx2048m` it couldn't install .apk :/